# Spring versions incompatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a project where we use Spring and Spring Security.

Our current Spring version is `4.0.6.RELEASE` and our Spring Security version is `4.0.0.M1`. I try to migrate to higher version of Spring Security `4.0.2 Release` but when I run my web app some functionality throws `NoSuchMethodError`. I read that this may be incompatibility of versions. My question is what is the best Security for Spring's current's version?

Comment: Of course the latest security APIs will be the best, that's just common sense since it's the latest release. But if you're getting these errors, you should find a stacktrace when running and see what method you are using that may not be in the API you're using. It also helps to use STS/Eclipse because it would mostly point these dependencies out for you.

Comment: appendix `RELEASE` is recommended. Other versions are in developing process and could be unstable.

Comment: Found the solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security will be compiled and built on specific Spring version. And below is the compatible version of Spring Security with Spring version.

```
Spring security 4.0.2.RELEASE is built on Spring version 4.3.2.RELEASE
Spring security 4.0.1.RELEASE is built on Spring version 4.3.2.RELEASE
Spring security 4.0.0.RELEASE is built on Spring version 4.1.6.RELEASE
```

In your case, as your Spring version is 4.0.6.RELEASE, so you should not upgrade your Spring Security version else you may get errors like `NoClassDefFound` or `NoSuchMethod`.

In fact you should use Spring Security version as 3.2.9.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have the following dependency for Spring Security:

```
spring-security-web
spring-security-config
spring-security-taglibs
spring-security-test
```

This dependencies set default `spring-security-core` to default version `3.2.4.RELEASE` which doesn't have all methods which the higher Spring Security methods use.

The Solution is to add `spring-security-core` dependency which override the default version.